# How can I Send Search and Get Data Back with Laravel 5 Paginator

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, datatables

I'm using Laravel 5 to paginate my data, it works well. Now it shows me 10 records out of hundreds. Now I want to search records not from the present on the page (which are only 10), but from the db and it should be displayed on my page.

How can I do this?
Any help please!!!

Note: I'm using dataTableJs library as well, but it looks not good. It loads all the data then makes its pagination on client. This is also not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
use DB;
```

After

```
$r = DB::table('your table');
// your query for exemple
$r->select('*')->where('column','like','%value%');
$results = $r->paginate(10);
return view('yourview',['results'=>$results]);
```

in your blade

```
 @foreach ($results as $result)
        {{ $result->Anycolumn; }}
@endforeach

{{$results->links()}}
```

to pass $_GET in your pagination

in controller q: name of your input

```
$q= $request->get('q');
     return view('yourview',['results'=>$results,'q'=>$q]);
```

in blade

```
{{($results->appends(Request::only(['q']))->links())}}
```

Comment: I guess 'q' would be a textbox, how would this 'q' get passed to the search criteria in controller? I'll have to send it using jquer/js/ajax or Laravel will do it?

Comment: and one more thing, I'm using Laravel 5. I don't have link() method. instead using render() method.
Is it also a method of LengthAwarePaginator class?

Comment: Thanks @anasmorahhib, I've solved the issue

Comment: sorry I have not seen your comment see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Comment: method 2: You can just do {{ $users->appends(request()->query())->links() }}, no need for except()

source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19441